# Habit in org to trigger by another task?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

I'm trying to create a unique habit and as usual, I'm over complicating things. I'll try to explain:

Let's say my mom always nags me about coming to see her, and as soon as I leave, she's asking when am I coming again, and why I never call...

I want to create a habit to call my mom once a week, but I want this habit to start only three days after I already saw her in person. So two different tasks are involved here: the visit, which triggers the calling habit.

So, let's say I saw my mom on Saturday. I want the habit graph to show the green range to call my mom only from Tuesday to Tuesday on next week.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: What determines when you visit?

Comment: that's manual... on my agenda I will schedule when I visit as an event (a header with a date and time). When the visit is done, I will enter the keyword "DONE" to this event.

Comment: OK - you should add that to the question.